# How to change some particular characters on TextView?

Tags: android, spannable

I need to change color of each vowel letter in TextView.
For example i have ("a", "e", "i", "o", "u") and i need them to be something like this -

```html
GR<font color='green'>EE</font>N C<font color='green'>O</font>L<font color='green'>O</font>R
```

I was trying this:

```
    if(text.contains("o")){
        SpannableString spanText = new SpannableString(text);

        // make "text" (characters pos-1 to pos) red
        spanText.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN), text.indexOf("o") - 1, text.indexOf("o"), 0);
        labelTextView.setText(spanText, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
    }
```

But i need more difficult changing of SpannableString, but don't know how.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could wrap your individual colors in html color tags, and use [Html.fromHtml(String string);](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml(java.lang.String)) to get your Span.

If you need a more difficult string color concatenation you could define a method to wrap individual portions of the string in your html and concatenate the result.

Edit:

I'm sure there's a more efficient way to do this, but this works.  If you want to map multiple different colors you'll have to extend the logic.

```
public String wrapVowelsInColor(String input){
    final List<String> VOWELS = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new String[] {"a", "A", "e", "E" ,"i", "I", "o", "O", "u", "U"}));

    final char[] mChars = input.toCharArray();
    final int count = mChars.length;
    final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(count);
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
        String current = String.valueOf(mChars[i]);
        if(VOWELS.contains(current)){
            builder.append(wrapInColor("blue", current)));
        } else {
            builder.append(current);
        }
    }

    return builder.toString();
}

public String wrapInColor(String color, String toWrap){
    return String.format("<font color='%s'>%s</font>", color, toWrap);
}
```

Input:

```
String testString = "My test string for coloring vowels";
```

Output:

```
My t<font color='blue'>e</font>st str<font color='blue'>i</font>ng f<font color='blue'>o</font>r c<font color='blue'>o</font>l<font color='blue'>o</font>r<font color='blue'>i</font>ng v<font color='blue'>o</font>w<font color='blue'>e</font>ls
```

Then just run `Html.fromHtml(String string)` on the output before setting the span on your `TextView`.

Comment: this method is good and simple, but i need to change all vowel letters in String that i'm getting.